# SQL Max Length (total combined) of multiple columns

Tags: sql, max

im very new to SQL and need some advice please. I'll keep it brief

I have 3 address columns which have fixed maximum lengths:

```
Add1 - Max 30
Add2 - Max 20
Add3 - Max 20
```

I need a query to find the longest complete address (combination of Add1+Add2+Add3)

I had tried using the following but I think what it was giving me was just the maxlength value of them all as individual columns, which I know is 30

```
SELECT MAX(len(T.Address)) AS MaxOfAddress
FROM (
    SELECT add_1 AS Address
    FROM table 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT add_2 AS Address
    FROM table 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT add_2 AS Address
    FROM table) AS T
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this query:

```
select 
    max(len(add_1)+len(add_2)+len(add_3)) Col
from
    table
```

For the data, please try:

```
select TOP 1 *
From table
order by len(add_1)+len(add_2)+len(add_3) desc
```

Comment: +1 this is nice, but need some more work as he wants the actual address not its length

Comment: @CodeBird Please check the added answer.

Comment: That sorted it. Thanks very much for all your help. Much aprpeciated

Answer (score 1):

A version that will probably work with most DBMS would be:

```
select add_1, add_2, add_3
from T
where length(trim(add_1)) + length(trim(add_2)) + length(trim(add_3))
    = ( select max(len) 
        from (
         select 
         length(trim(add_1)) + length(trim(add_2)) + length(trim(add_3)) as len
         from T
        )
      )
```

if add_n can be null you can use something like:

```
coalesce(trim(add_1),'')
```

to handle that.

If your DBMS support Common Table Expressions (CTE) it is probably more efficient to use that. Something like:

```
with cte (add_1,add_2,add_3,len) as ( 
    select add_1,add_2,add_3 
         , length(trim(add_1))+length(trim(add_3))+length(trim(add_3)) from T 
) 
select add_1,add_2,add_3 
from cte 
where len = (select max(len) from cte)
```

Yet another option is if your DBMS support analytical functions such as row_number:

```
select add_1,add_2,add_3
from (
    select add_1,add_2,add_3
         , row_number() over ( 
           order by length(trim(add_1))+length(trim(add_3))+length(trim(add_3)) desc
           ) as rn 
    from t
) where rn = 1
```

or you could

```
select add_1,add_2,add_3
from T
order by length(trim(add_1))+length(trim(add_3))+length(trim(add_3)) desc
fetch first 1 rows only
```

Comment: +1 for all the good solutions and the long answer from a new user!